# Salvar estado do spinner

Tags: android, android-studio, spinners

Gostaria de saber como faz pra, após selecionar uma opção do spinner, deixa-la salva na hora do formulario para alteração, exemplo: escolho a opção 2, quando for na hora de alterar o formulario, a opção selecionada do spinner será a opção 2, não a opção1

Comment: Use `posicao = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()` para obter a posição do item seleccionado, guarde-o da mesma forma que guarda os outros dados do formulário. Na altura de alterar actualize a selecção no *Spinner* através de `spinner.setSelection(posicao);`

Comment: mas vou precisar depois disso, salvar posicao no banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, deve guardar no banco junto com os outros dados do formulário.

Comment: Os dados que preenchem o *Spinner* também estão banco de dados?

Comment: me salvou, sem mais, acabei meu TCC!

Comment: como eu finalizo diznedo que vc me ajudo e ajudo na reputação?

Comment: Não é necessário fazer nada, para mim chega saber que pude ajudar.

Comment: Eu tambem estou estudando isso, por favor @ramaral, nao eh preciso usar o ID do spinner? como diferenciar dos outros spinners na mesma pagina?

Comment: Deverá ter um campo na tabela para cada spinner.